# How can a CFI renew their certificate with the FAA during the government shutdown?

Tags: faa

My CFI certificate expires at the end of the month. I have completed the required Flight Instructor Renewal Course ("FIRC"), but when I called my local FSDO to make an appointment to submit my renewal application for a new CFI certificate I discovered that the FAA is shut down. If the shutdown continues through my CFI expiration date, can I renew my certificate with the FAA after the expiration date?

Comment: What is the name of the policing agency that prevents you from operating without the certificate?

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri I'm not sure if that was a serious question, but [this](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/23437/62) may be relevant. It's also worth considering that your insurance company will refuse coverage if they have evidence that you weren't operating in accordance with the regulations. Giving instruction without a valid CFI certificate world certainly be in that category. That could turn a minor incident into a cripplingly expensive one.

Comment: My question was intended as a potential trigger for what I hoped would be a serious discussion - Thank you for your informative remark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer is no, but there is a way to renew your CFI while Federal Government is shutdown. However, it's not through the FAA because so long as the FAA is shut down it cannot process applications.

(After a few hours of freaking out at the thought of having to redo my CFII check ride, I discovered there is a solution to this.

While the FAA is not processing applications during the government shutdown, the FAA has authorized certain non-federal employees to accept and process airmen applications for CFI renewal ***AND to issue temporary flight instructor certificates.*** These are called Airman Certification Representatives (ACR), and are defined as:

> **Airman Certification Representative (ACR).** An ACR is an individual representing a specific FIRC provider who is authorized under Title 49
>   of the United States Code (49 U.S.C.) § 44702(d) to accept airmen
>   applications for renewal of a valid flight instructor certificate from
>   successful graduates of that provider’s FIRC and to issue temporary
>   flight instructor certificates

Source: [Advisory Circular 61-83J](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/AC_61-83J.pdf).

Comment: You may also find a DPE who is authorized to renew the certificate as well.