# Is it legal to build your own plane and fly it?

Tags: faa-regulations, usa, airplane

Is it legal to build and fly your own airplane? This essentially leads to two central questions: **Will the FAA even let you build and fly your own airplane?**, and **Will there need to be inspections and testing records to certify it as flightworthy and legal before being able to fly it?**

Say I built my own plane, a large plane. 3 Propellers powering the plane. Amphibious, can land and take off on a runway or on the water. It's red, if this makes any real difference. And it is built to support 2 people and is supposed to be able to fly for up to 1 week without refueling. That being said, if the plane crashes it'll cause quite some damage. And to fly for 1 week supporting 2 people and quite a lot of cargo in the form of food and other essentials, the airplane is *loaded* with fuel.

If I know the plane floats on the water, could I fly it in an unpopulated area in short testing runs, or is that considered illegal? This also brings the question, Is there is a limit to how much fuel a plane can legally carry in a single flight? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you read through the FAA regulations (in the FARs) concerning experimental aircraft? Limitations are pretty clearly spelled out...

Comment: Could you link those regulations, by chance? That would help quite a lot. Thank you.

Comment: Most of your challenges will be from the laws of physics, not the FAA.

Comment: There is an irreparable conflict with realms of regulations and physics here. According to regulations building and flying is totally possible (albeit **extremely** laborous, accounting for design, building and the red tape), but the plane described is not possible, not if the specified week of operating consists of even 1/10 of flight time (~17 h). Twin Otter as an example: fuel burn ~575lb/h, fuel capacity ~2500lb, max weight ~12500lb, so fuel about 20% of max w. for 17 h of flying you'd need ~10000lb of fuel, so very rough estimate of max w is about 50000lb. IRL it's even worse.

Comment: @ob318 There is no reason to put "under FAA regulations" into the title, as the question is already tagged such. Per this [StackExchange Meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles) it is simply not needed, even for search engine optimization.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's legal. The FAA has [an amateur-built aircraft homepage](https://www.faa.gov/aircraft/gen_av/ultralights/amateur_built/) with links to regulations, guidance etc.

It's also very common. The Experimental Aircraft Association [has a lot of resources](https://www.eaa.org/eaa/aircraft-building) too.

Comment: But can I fly the plane without completing those forms? And another question for people with a similar issue but that don't have pilot licenses, Could a person fly their own plane without a pilot license? (The controls could be all wack, being however the builder wanted it)

Comment: @Ginger In the US, you can't "operate" an "aircraft" (definitions in 14 CFR 1.1) unless it's registered (14 CFR 91.203(a)) and you have a pilot's certificate (14 CFR 61.3(a)). Ultralights are exempt from those requirements. Flying without a pilot's certificate is [not recommended](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/23437/62).

Comment: Needless to say, the concept in question here will *not* fit the ultralights category :)